# UserWarning: no type annotations present -- not typechecking test... (def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): # type: ignore[no-untyped-def])

Tags: python, warnings, keyword-argument, typechecking

### Context

Suppose one creates a test object, and during its initialization, one also creates some test object properties, like shown below:

```py
class Test_mdsa(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests whether MDSA algorithm specification detects invalid
    specifications."""

    # Initialize test object
    @typechecked
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mdsa = MDSA(list(range(0, 4, 1)))
        self.mdsa_configs = get_algo_configs(self.mdsa.__dict__)
        verify_algo_configs("MDSA", self.mdsa_configs)
```

### Warning message

It shows the following warning (upon running `python -m pytest -k the_test`:

> ./../anaconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typeguard/**init**.py:1016

> /home/name/anaconda/envs/snncompare/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typeguard

> /**init**.py:1016: UserWarning: no type annotations present -- not typechecking test_mdsa_propagation.Test_mdsa.**init**
> warn('no type annotations present -- not typechecking {}'.format(function_name(func)))

### Question

How can one alleviated this warning (without suppressing the warning), or give the correct types or tell the typechecker to ignore the `*arg, **kwargs` in the initialisation?

### Approach I

I thought the `# type: ignore[no-untyped-def]` was an acceptable way to handle this, however, it does not seem to be picked up by the warning system.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I should add the `-> None:` at the end of the `__init__()`, and that removed the warning when I added:

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:  # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

### Limitations

However, in that case any additional arguments like:

```py
def __init__(self, some_fish:Fish, *args, **kwargs) -> None:  # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
```

will also not be typechecked. At the same time, I did not yet find a use case in which additional `__init__()` arguments are necessary for a test.